# Unable to stretch Label in tkinter root

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using python 3.7 and I am unable to stretch the labels to fill all the available space horizontally.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry('500x600')
root.title("Test")
root.configure(background='black')

sym = tkinter.StringVar()

def symsel():
   print(sym.get())

Labelgap1 = Label( root,bg="Green",height = 1)
Labelgap1.grid(row =0 ,column=0,sticky="nsew")
Labelgap1.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

Labelgap2 = Label( root,bg="Green",text = " Contracts",height = 2,relief = RAISED)
Labelgap2.grid(row =3 ,column=0,sticky="nsew")
Labelgap2.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

Radiobutton1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(root, bg = "black",text="Rdb1",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton1",font=("Courier", 15), command=symsel, tristatevalue=0)  
Radiobutton1.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew") 
Radiobutton2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(root,bg = "black", text="Radb2",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton2", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=5)    
Radiobutton2.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")
Radiobutton3 = tkinter.Radiobutton(root,bg = "black", text="Rdb3",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton3", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=5)   
Radiobutton3.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")
Radiobutton4 = tkinter.Radiobutton(root,bg = "black", text="Rdb4",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton4", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=3)   
Radiobutton4.grid(row=1,column=3,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")
Radiobutton5 = tkinter.Radiobutton(root,bg = "black", text="Rdb5",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton5", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=1)   
Radiobutton5.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")
Radiobutton6 = tkinter.Radiobutton(root,bg = "black", text="Rdb6",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton6", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=5)   
Radiobutton6.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")
Radiobutton7 = tkinter.Radiobutton(root,bg = "black", text="Rdb7",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton7", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=4)  
Radiobutton7.grid(row=2,column=2,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")
Radiobutton8 = tkinter.Radiobutton(root,bg = "black", text="Rdb8",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton7", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=2)   
Radiobutton8.grid(row=2,column=3,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")

root.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight = 1)
root.mainloop()
```

This code  results in the output :
[image: GUI]

When I maximise this GUI to windows screen it becomes :
[image: GUIMAX]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your labels are in the zeroth column and there are 4 columns of radiobuttons. So, when you do `grid_columnconfigure`, the labels will expand as much as possible, but tkinter also has to fit the other three columns. This is why, they don't expand to screen size.

For this, you can change the `columnspan` of the labels to say, 4.

I also see, you have used grid_columnconfigure on the labels as well. I hope you realize this won't achieve anything.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x600')
root.title("Test")
root.configure(background='black')

sym = tk.StringVar()

def symsel():
   print(sym.get())

Labelgap1 = tk.Label(root, bg="Green", height = 1)
Labelgap1.grid(row =0 ,column=0, sticky="nsew", columnspan=4)

Labelgap2 = tk.Label(root, bg="Green", text = "Contracts", height = 2, relief = "raised")
Labelgap2.grid(row =3 ,column=0, sticky="nsew", columnspan=4)

Radiobutton1 = tk.Radiobutton(root, bg = "black",text="Rdb1",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton1",font=("Courier", 15), command=symsel, tristatevalue=0)  
Radiobutton1.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew") 
Radiobutton2 = tk.Radiobutton(root,bg = "black", text="Rdb2",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton2", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=5)    
Radiobutton2.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")
Radiobutton3 = tk.Radiobutton(root,bg = "black", text="Rdb3",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton3", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=5)   
Radiobutton3.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")
Radiobutton4 = tk.Radiobutton(root,bg = "black", text="Rdb4",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton4", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=3)   
Radiobutton4.grid(row=1,column=3,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")
Radiobutton5 = tk.Radiobutton(root,bg = "black", text="Rdb5",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton5", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=1)   
Radiobutton5.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")
Radiobutton6 = tk.Radiobutton(root,bg = "black", text="Rdb6",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton6", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=5)   
Radiobutton6.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")
Radiobutton7 = tk.Radiobutton(root,bg = "black", text="Rdb7",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton7", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=4)  
Radiobutton7.grid(row=2,column=2,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")
Radiobutton8 = tk.Radiobutton(root,bg = "black", text="Rdb8",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton7", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=2)   
Radiobutton8.grid(row=2,column=3,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")

root.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight = 1)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

---

You may also want to have the radiobuttons of the same dimensions (Right now they aren't because only zeroth column is expanding. Other columns won't.). For that you can put them in a frame and then you don't have to worry about the columnspans anymore as all will be in the zeroth column.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x600')
root.title("Test")
root.configure(background='black')

sym = tk.StringVar()

def symsel():
   print(sym.get())

Labelgap1 = tk.Label(root, bg="Green", height = 1)
Labelgap1.grid(row=0 ,column=0, sticky="nsew")

Labelgap2 = tk.Label(root, bg="Green", text = "Contracts", height = 2, relief = "raised")
Labelgap2.grid(row=2 ,column=0, sticky="nsew")

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
frame.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight = 1)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight = 1)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(2,weight = 1)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(3,weight = 1)

Radiobutton1 = tk.Radiobutton(frame, bg = "black",text="Rdb1",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton1",font=("Courier", 15), command=symsel, tristatevalue=0)  
Radiobutton1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew") 
Radiobutton2 = tk.Radiobutton(frame,bg = "black", text="Rdb2",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton2", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=5)    
Radiobutton2.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")
Radiobutton3 = tk.Radiobutton(frame,bg = "black", text="Rdb3",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton3", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=5)   
Radiobutton3.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")
Radiobutton4 = tk.Radiobutton(frame,bg = "black", text="Rdb4",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton4", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=3)   
Radiobutton4.grid(row=0,column=3,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")
Radiobutton5 = tk.Radiobutton(frame,bg = "black", text="Rdb5",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton5", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=1)   
Radiobutton5.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")
Radiobutton6 = tk.Radiobutton(frame,bg = "black", text="Rdb6",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton6", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=5)   
Radiobutton6.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")
Radiobutton7 = tk.Radiobutton(frame,bg = "black", text="Rdb7",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton7", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=4)  
Radiobutton7.grid(row=1,column=2,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")
Radiobutton8 = tk.Radiobutton(frame,bg = "black", text="Rdb8",fg="Green", variable=sym, value="Radiobutton7", font=("Courier", 15),command=symsel, tristatevalue=2)   
Radiobutton8.grid(row=1,column=3,padx=2, pady= 5,sticky = "nsew")

root.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight = 1)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) it worked. Another question .. why are rdb 1 and rdb5 buttons bigger than the rest of them?

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for help :)